# Check if given email exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to know if the email entered by user is real in Firebase? Does the built-in sign up with email&password method have this feature?

EDIT: sorry for the misunderstanding . I don't care if the email has been used before , what I need to know is: if the entered email is 'made-up' or 'real , exists'

Comment: You're probably looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090406/ambiguous-use-of-subscript-swift-3/40092330#40092330

Comment: If you want to know whether the email address is actually owned by the user, your app can call user.sendEmailVerification(): https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Answer (score 40):

This is another solution without any create user or sign in processes.

```
//check email already exist or not.
    firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {

                    boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getSignInMethods().isEmpty();

                    if (isNewUser) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Is New User!");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Is Old User!");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: If user exists with the email , then how to get UID of that user using this method ?

Comment: I think this solution is much better than all above mentioned solutions.

Comment: This should be on the top!!

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can do that either you create new account or signing in:

For creating, read `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`'s [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` throws 3 exceptions:

1. `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException`: if the password is not strong enough
2. `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException`: if the email address is malformed
3. `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException`: **if there already exists an account with the given email address**.

You can handle that in `onCompleteListener` or `onFailureListener`

Here an example where `mAuth` is `FirebaseAuth` instance:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }
                                // if user enters wrong email.
                                catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException weakPassword)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: weak_password");

                                    // TODO: take your actions!
                                }
                                // if user enters wrong password.
                                catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException malformedEmail)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: malformed_email");

                                    // TODO: Take your action
                                }
                                catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException existEmail)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: exist_email");

                                    // TODO: Take your action
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

For signing in, read `signInWithEmailAndPassword`'s [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) first.

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` throws two exceptions:

1. `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException`: if email doesn't exist or disabled.
2. `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException`: if password is wrong

Here is an example:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }
                                // if user enters wrong email.
                                catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException invalidEmail)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: invalid_email");

                                    // TODO: take your actions!
                                }
                                // if user enters wrong password.
                                catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException wrongPassword)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: wrong_password");

                                    // TODO: Take your action
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Comment: if you enter an email does not exist with your code the result is always wrong password...

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** To check if user is 'made-up' or 'real', just send an email verification by calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()` and ask user to click the link sent in their email, if user is able to perform this action then email exists otherwise it's 'made-up'. Later you can check if email is verified or not by using this boolean `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.emailVerified`. Hope this answers your question.

**OLD ANSWER:** In case someone is looking for a flutter answer, then a rather easiest way would be to just check if `List<String>` returned by `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` contains `'password'` string or not.

Here is sample code:

```cpp
var methods = await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
if (methods.contains('password')) {
  ///  Email exists
}
else {
  ///  Email does not exist
}
```

Original source (google codelabs): https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/4397b60355daab38e98ca967c47af9b7671e0fd9/firebase-get-to-know-flutter/step_05/lib/main.dart#L122

Comment: You can also use `EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` , `GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID`, `FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` for checking which is much safer and cleaner

Answer (score 1):

This maybe late answer but just for someone passing by could get benefit from the answer. I think the best way to check if the email is exist or not is to send the verification email to the inputing email.

Try checking out this link

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html

Firebase has provided really easy way to verify user email.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
task.getException().getMessage() to get the exception

Answer (score -3):

It would be almost impossible to check if the email entered exists, you can however check if the email string entered conforms to the valid email structure:

```
if(!isValidEmail(etEmail.getText().toString())) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid input for email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Then like Jin Liu suggests, use the sendEmailVerification(), like:

```
 mFirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Email Verfication Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    try{
                        throw task.getException();
                    }catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```