# I'm having problem with Firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying make firebase auth using email/password and Google auth.  Email/password login works fine but I'm having an issue about one email per account. After I sign up with email/password, and try to login with Google auth,  then errors should appear about saying "auth/email account -already in use",  but instead, it just logs in like normal behavior.
I'm very confused.  I was going to make account link to same email account but I'm not sure what to do next since this weird behavior happened. I will be sooo great if someone explain it to me about this issue.  This is based on React.js and React-router and firebase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if given email exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093781/check-if-given-email-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Google Auth is Gmail and hence has a "higher authority".

If you can sign-in with your Gmail/Password, you are identified as the **email address owner**, and hence have the authority to login to your firebase account.

If you try to sign-in with Facebook, after you sign up with email/password, you will get the error "auth/email account -already in use" which you want to see.

This is the correct firebase behaviour.