# How to check if an email exists in Firebase Authentication?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to check if an email already exists in Firebase authentication, but I can find something for Java.
I am trying to do something like searching in a list of emails and if that email is not in the database (emailNotExistsInDatabase(email)), then continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the very complete response from Alex, another possible approach is to use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that you call from your app.

Since we use the Admin SDK in Cloud Functions you can use the [`getUserByEmail()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth#baseauthgetuserbyemail) method.

The function would look like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.checkEmailExists = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return admin.auth()
        .getUserByEmail(data.email)
        .then((userRecord) => {
            return { emailExists: true }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', "email doesn't exist");
        });

});
```

With this approach you don't need a specific Firestore collection. The Admin SDK will directly query the Auth service.

Look at the doc for instructions on [how to call the Callable Cloud Function from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).

---

Note that the above approach is valid if you want to check if a user exists from an application (e.g. an Android app).

If you already use [the Admin SDK from a  Java based **server**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), you just have to use the `getUserByEmail()` method in your server code.

Comment: Thanks, I used the getUserByEmail and it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is no method inside the [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) class that can help you check the existence of a user based on an email address. If you need that functionality you have to create it yourself. This means that when a user signs in for the first time into your app, then save user data in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) using a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
     |
     --- $uid (document)
          |
          --- email: "user-email@gmail.com"
```

To check if a user with the `user-email@gmail.com` already exists, then you have to perform a query that looks like this in Java:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query queryByEmail = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("email", "user-email@gmail.com");
queryByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User already exists.");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User doesn't exist.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Another solution would be to use [Query#count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#count()) method:

```
queryByEmail.count();
```

If the result is > 0 then it means that the user already exists, otherwise it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I used the getUserByEmail and it solved the problem! In case my case I didn't have the email in uid collection in firebase, but I will add it since it's better that way!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a given email address is associated with a user profile in Firebase, you can call the [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)).

Note that this API gives malicious users a way to perform a so-called enumeration attack, so you can actually nowadays [disable `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.devsite.corp.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#enumeration-protection) - in which case calling it from your app would fail.

Also see:

- [Check if given email exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093781/check-if-given-email-exists)
- [Check if an email already exists in Firebase Auth in Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652134/check-if-an-email-already-exists-in-firebase-auth-in-flutter-app)

**Update**: Since September 15, 2023 the protection mentioned above is enabled for all new projects you create on Firebase, so you can no longer use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` on those projects unless you disabled the protection first.

Comment: I didn't have the fetchSignInMethodForEmail but I used the getUserByEmail and that solved my issue. I will take a look in the method you mentioned, because it's also a good approach. Thanks again!

Comment: `fetchSignInMethodForEmail` is a method in the client-side SDKs, while `getUserByEmail` is in the server-side/Admin SDKs. Either can be used to implement the use-case, but I had overlooked you were using non-Android Java.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio ****Firestore Database Exists or Not Exists ** Checking Email id**

try below Step

```
    Query emailExists = db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("email", user.get("email"));

    emailExists.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    
                    if (task.getResult().isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "User Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "User Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.d("TAG", "User doesn't exist: ");
     });
```

Only Firestore Database Try

**Thank You**